# Inconsistent null assignment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, pass-by-value

Could not assign null values to the following code

```cs
    [Table("POSMachine")]
    public class POSMachine
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string POSSN { get; set; }
        public int? ReceivedBy { get; set; }
        public int? ReceivedFrom { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ReceivedFrom")]
        public virtual TeamMember ReceivedFromMember { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ReceivedBy")]
        public virtual TeamMember ReceivedByMember { get; set; }
    }

    private void LoadMachineObj(POSMachine machine)
    {
        var receivebymember = _context.TeamMembers.Where(m => m.IsActive == true && m.ID == receivebyid).FirstOrDefault();
            machine.ReceivedByMember = receivebymember;
        var receivefrommember = _context.TeamMembers.Where(m => m.IsActive == true && m.ID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        machine.ReceivedFromMember = receivefrommember;
    }

//calling method:
    var machine = _context.POSMachines.Where(v => v.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    LoadMachineObj(machine);
    _context.Entry(machine).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

If `receivefrommember` variable is null `machine.ReceivedFromMember` holds the previous object reference something like `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TeamMember_98A56E4F3F20CCE075A377A6C5A2A9E1C6BFE2A0F00566726C986B9313FBB82C`. But sometimes becomes null. If `receivefrommember` is null why `machine.ReceivedFromMember` becomes null sometimes and not null sometimes.Is my entity object defination correct?

Comment: `ReceivedFromMember` is virtual property, maybe it's overridden somewhere?

Comment: How you are using this method?